Trouble codes alternating between P0011 and P0012 on 2011 Hyundai Accent
My check engine light is on, and the codes seem to alternate between P0011 and P0012:
P0011: "A" Camshaft Position - Timing Over-Advanced or System Performance (Bank 1)
P0012: "A" Camshaft Position - Timing Over-Retarded (Bank 1)

They don't happen at the same time, not even as pending codes.
The car is a 2011 Hyundai Accent ("MC" generation).
Things I've done:

Replaced the oil and filter
Replaced the oil control valve
Cleaned the oil control valve filter
Replaced the camshaft position sensor
Replaced the VVT actuator
Replaced the timing belt and tensioner

What else could the problem be?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You said you changed the oil ... are you positive the correct weight oil was utilized?

Thanks! I used 5W-20, which is what the oil cap says.

Cool ... the oil weight can affect how the VVT works, so it is important the right oil be added. Synthetic versus dino oil makes a difference as well. I believe most VVT engines (of whatever flavor) specify for synthetic.
